# Ruby on Rails Failure/Error on all examples

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, rest, ruby-on-rails-6

I am following this guide on building a restful json api https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/build-a-restful-json-api-with-rails-5-part-one#project-setup

I have followed every single step up until the models area ( there are 5 areas, Prerequisites, Project Setup,Models,Controllers,Conclusion) where the testing begins ...
however when I am trying to run any tests all my examples (5 of them) are all failed.

```
C:\Users\nion1\todos-api>bundle exec rspec
FFFFF
Failures:

1) Item
 Failure/Error: example.run
   `name` is not available from within an example (e.g. an `it` block) or from constructs that run in the scope of an example (e.g. `before`, `let`, etc). It is only available on an example group (e.g. a `describe` or `context` block).
 # ./spec/rails_helper.rb:53:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./spec/rails_helper.rb:52:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

2) Item
 Failure/Error: example.run
   `name` is not available from within an example (e.g. an `it` block) or from constructs that run in the scope of an example (e.g. `before`, `let`, etc). It is only available on an example group (e.g. a `describe` or `context` block).
 # ./spec/rails_helper.rb:53:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./spec/rails_helper.rb:52:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

3) Todo
 Failure/Error: example.run
   `name` is not available from within an example (e.g. an `it` block) or from constructs that run in the scope of an example (e.g. `before`, `let`, etc). It is only available on an example group (e.g. a `describe` or `context` block).
 # ./spec/rails_helper.rb:53:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./spec/rails_helper.rb:52:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

4) Todo
 Failure/Error: example.run
   `name` is not available from within an example (e.g. an `it` block) or from constructs that run in the scope of an example (e.g. `before`, `let`, etc). It is only available on an example group (e.g. a `describe` or `context` block).
 # ./spec/rails_helper.rb:53:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./spec/rails_helper.rb:52:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

5) Todo
 Failure/Error: example.run
   `name` is not available from within an example (e.g. an `it` block) or from constructs that run in the scope of an example (e.g. `before`, `let`, etc). It is only available on an example group (e.g. a `describe` or `context` block).
 # ./spec/rails_helper.rb:53:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./spec/rails_helper.rb:52:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

 Finished in 0.10099 seconds (files took 1.52 seconds to load)
 5 examples, 5 failures

 Failed examples:

 rspec ./spec/models/item_spec.rb:8 # Item
 rspec ./spec/models/item_spec.rb:11 # Item
 rspec ./spec/models/todo_spec.rb:8 # Todo
 rspec ./spec/models/todo_spec.rb:11 # Todo
 rspec ./spec/models/todo_spec.rb:12 # Todo
```

I am really trying to understand a way to fix this error but i just cant figure it out..
Any ideas ? Anything would be really helpful
my files :

**rails_helper.rb**:

```
require 'spec_helper'
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'

require File.expand_path('../config/environment', __dir__)

# Prevent database truncation if the environment is production
abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?
require 'rspec/rails'
# Add additional requires below this line. Rails is not loaded until this point!
Shoulda::Matchers.configure do |config|
  config.integrate do |with|
    with.test_framework :rspec
    with.library :rails
  end
end

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc, in
# spec/support/ and its subdirectories. Files matching `spec/**/*_spec.rb` are
# run as spec files by default. This means that files in spec/support that end
# in _spec.rb will both be required and run as specs, causing the specs to be
# run twice. It is recommended that you do not name files matching this glob to
# end with _spec.rb. You can configure this pattern with the --pattern
# option on the command line or in ~/.rspec, .rspec or `.rspec-local`.
#
# The following line is provided for convenience purposes. It has the downside
# of increasing the boot-up time by auto-requiring all files in the support
# directory. Alternatively, in the individual `*_spec.rb` files, manually
# require only the support files necessary.
#
# Dir[Rails.root.join('spec', 'support', '**', '*.rb')].each { |f| require f }

# Checks for pending migrations and applies them before tests are run.
# If you are not using ActiveRecord, you can remove these lines.
begin
  ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!
rescue ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError => e
  puts e.to_s.strip
  exit 1
end
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.include FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods
  # start by truncating all the tables but then use the faster transaction strategy the rest of the time.
  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end

  # start the transaction strategy as examples are run
  config.around(:each) do |example|
    DatabaseCleaner.cleaning do
      example.run
    end
  end
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  # RSpec Rails can automatically mix in different behaviours to your tests
  # based on their file location, for example enabling you to call `get` and
  # `post` in specs under `spec/controllers`.
  #
  # You can disable this behaviour by removing the line below, and instead
  # explicitly tag your specs with their type, e.g.:
  #
  #     RSpec.describe UsersController, :type => :controller do
  #       # ...
  #     end
  #
  # The different available types are documented in the features, such as in
  # https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!

  # Filter lines from Rails gems in backtraces.
  config.filter_rails_from_backtrace!
  # arbitrary gems may also be filtered via:
  # config.filter_gems_from_backtrace("gem name")
end
```

**spec/models/todo_spec.rb**:

```
require 'rails_helper'

# Test suite for the Todo model
RSpec.describe Todo, type: :model do
  # Association test
  # ensure Todo model has a 1:m relationship with the Item model
  it { should have_many(:items).dependent(:destroy) }
  # Validation tests
  # ensure columns title and created_by are present before saving
  it { should validate_presence_of(:title) }
  it { should validate_presence_of(:created_by) }
end
```

**item_spec.rb**:

```
require 'rails_helper'

# Test suite for the Item model
RSpec.describe Item, type: :model do
  # Association test
  # ensure an item record belongs to a single todo record
  it { should belong_to(:todo) }
  # Validation test
  # ensure column name is present before saving
  it { should validate_presence_of(:name) }
end
```

Comment: exception is thrown on line _./spec/rails_helper.rb:53:in_ - did you check what is called there which can raise such error?

Comment: example.run is called but i dont know what that does .. since i am following the tutorial that i have listed

Comment: you probably get more information about the error by removing line `config.filter_rails_from_backtrace!` in rails helper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so the problem seemed to be the version of ruby and rails.

For some reason ruby 2.7.2 and Rails 6.0.3.4 worked for my problem.

Of course GemFile needs to be changed

Answer (score 5):

Upgrading shoulda-matchers and rspec-rails to the latest versions worked for me

Comment: Same here, I had `rspec-rails` pinned to < 4.0, which caused issues with Rails 6.1. Make sure to use `gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 4.0'` in your Gemfile.

Comment: For me the fix was to update the Gemfile as suggested by @slhck

Comment: Thanks Zakariae. This one worked for me as well. Just need to ensure all your test dependencies are updated to the latest stable version.

Answer (score 4):

I tried that tutorial as well. I am working with **Ruby 2.7.2** and **Rails 6.1.3**, I need to update the `gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 4.0'` in order to fix that issue.

Answer (score 0):

In the gem file if rspec's version is < 4 try to replace it with the latest version or with the below line.

> gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 4.0'

It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I solved, in my case function like was say here updating gem rspec-rails like below:
`gem 'rspec-rails', ~>4.0 gem 'shoulda-matchers', '~> 5.0'`

For rails 6.1.4.1 is fine